# React child component to invoke a function on a sibling componenet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

It's going to be hard to verbalise this question. In React, is there a way for a deeply (2 levels deep from the parent) nested child component to invoke a function that it has a sibling relationship with ? (the sibling being 1 level deep from the parent, but lacking a top-down relationship with the deeply nested child)

The function is meant to change the state of the sibling component, so it needs to be invoked as a method on the sibling component's class

See I know that I can pass a function as a prop to a child and have it get invoked on the parent's class, but can this happen with a sibling somehow?

Please let me know if this makes sense, if not I can throw together a simple example of what I mean, There is too much code for me to paste.

Comment: It's tough to understand the specifics of your situation but generally React advocates a uni-directional data flow.. data only flows one way, from parent to child. Is there some way you can move the related state from that sibling to the parent, and then have the function get passed down as you mention from parent to the other child?

Comment: Yes there is, and that is what I am trying to avoid to do because it will get messy, but it is the only solution I have been able to come up with... I don't think  there is a way to accomplish what I am trying here otherwise :(

Comment: Yeah co-located state is one of the big reasons alternative state management libs exist. It can get a little hairy passing all the various bits of state and state-updating functions throughout multiple levels of a component hierarchy. You can easily run into a spot where you have to pass props through components that don't even care about them just so their children have access. It's at that point that it's worth looking into either say Redux or potentially MobX, imo

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can invoke a function in a parent from a child by passing the function as a prop. In the parent you can then change some state which causes a re-render of the parent, passing the new state/props down to the sibling you want to update.